# Formatting new TableRow (Programmatically)

Tags: android, format, row, android-tablelayout

in XML I've definded a TableLayout with a TableRow (the headline of the table).
Every other row will be added programmatically. The problem: I can't get the new rows to line up with the one of the XML

1. 3 TextView Array, 1 TableRow Array
2. Loop to fill these arrays with TextViews and TableRows
3. All are given to the setTableRowParams method
4. Setting text for the TextViews
5. Adding all rows to the TableLayout

   ```
   driversNames = new TextView[DRIVERSAMOUNT];
   driversDriven = new TextView[DRIVERSAMOUNT];
   driversRemaining = new TextView[DRIVERSAMOUNT];
   driversRows = new TableRow[DRIVERSAMOUNT];

   for (int i = 0; i < DRIVERSAMOUNT; i++) {

       driversNames[i] = new TextView(this);
       driversDriven[i] = new TextView(this);
       driversRemaining[i] = new TextView(this);

       driversRows[i] = new TableRow(this);
       setTableRowParams(driversRows[i]);

       driversNames[i].setText(driversArray[i].getName());
       driversDriven[i].setText("" + driversArray[i].getTimeDriven());
       driversRemaining[i].setText("" + driversArray[i].getTimeRemaining());



       driversRows[i].addView(driversNames[i]);
       driversRows[i].addView(driversDriven[i]);
       driversRows[i].addView(driversRemaining[i]);

       tableLayout.addView(driversRows[i]);

   }
   ```

   setTableRowParams() Method

   ```
   TableLayout.LayoutParams tableRowParams =
           new TableLayout.LayoutParams
                   (TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
   tableRowParams.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);

   tr.setLayoutParams(tableRowParams);
   ```

   ```
       <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
           android:id="@+id/card_driver"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_gravity="center"
           android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
           android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
           android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
           android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
           android:elevation="10dp"
           card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp">

           <TableLayout
               android:id="@+id/tableDrivers"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content">

               <TableRow
                   android:id="@+id/driversRow1"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_margin="10dp">

                   <TextView
                       android:id="@+id/tVDriversTitle"
                       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_span="3"
                       android:layout_weight="1"
                       android:text="@string/card_drivers"
                       android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

               </TableRow>

               <TableRow
                   android:id="@+id/driversRow2"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_margin="10dp">

                   <TextView
                       android:id="@+id/tVDriversName"
                       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_weight="1"
                       android:text="@string/drivers"
                       android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                   <TextView
                       android:id="@+id/tVDriversDriven"
                       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_weight="1"
                       android:text="@string/timeDriven"
                       android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                   <TextView
                       android:id="@+id/tVDriversRemaining"
                       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_weight="1"
                       android:text="@string/timeLeft"
                       android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

               </TableRow>

               <!-- THE VALUES ARE ADDED PROGRAMATICALLY -->

           </TableLayout>

       </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
   ```

This is the result. As you can see the rows Driver 1-4 don't line up with the headline. Sorry for the foreign language ;-)[image]

Can you please tell me where my mistake is?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set the android:layout_width attribute to 0dp(and of course keep the android:layout_weight as 1) on the child views?

Make sure all children started of from the same width (android:layout_width="0dp" on both of them)

Comment: Thank you Fahim, but I'm not quiet sure what you mean. Which elements width should I set to 0dp? I've updated my question with the XML part.